How to get authentication code as returned by react-google-login in react native mobile app
I am working on react-native-google-login in the mobile app, but here I haven't found any way to get GoogleAuth object that will return a code like: (KYYjmc3f7fT9lnZM_BUklEQ9_5luhCNmPuQDrL67XD5SlF6f1x7MORxktu3HQmjTw)
as per react-google-login , documentation:
If responseType is not 'code', callback will return the GoogleAuth object.

If responseType is 'code', callback will return the authorization code that can be used to retrieve a refresh token from the server.

This react-google-login returns the GoogleAuth object that the backend team is using.
The API team is handling that code returned in react-google-login so I need to generate that code for successful implementation.
Currently, I am able to get the access token and userId token as:
GoogleSignin.getTokens().then(res => {
      var postData = {
        access_token: res.accessToken,
        code: data.idToken,
      };
    });

Please guide me whats the best way to achieve this or is the API needs to be updated.
TIA
